# Брелок для [к, от] автомобильной сигнализации — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Какой предлог правильно использовать?
*Он протянул мне брелок **для** [**к, от**] автомобильной сигнализации.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**брело́к**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&ro=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA), -ло́ка и *(разг.)* -лка́; **м.** [франц. *breloque*] Украшение — небольшая подвеска к цепочке карманных часов, браслету и т. п. *Брелок для ключей. Браслет с брелком.*

Брелок — это фитюлька, которая навешивается **на** что-то, прикрепляется **к** чему-то, цепляется **за** что-то (по определению).
Брелок **к** браслету, брелок **от** ключей, брелок **для** часов — эти предлоги, как мне кажется, нельзя применить к сигнализации, правильно говорить ***брелок сигнализации*.**

Говорить "брелок от машины" — неправильно. Аксессуар не "навешивается" на машину, а уж на сигнализацию — тем более!

*Вылезая из машины, он небрежным движением через плечо нажал на **брелок cигнализации.** «Ягуар» послушно чирикнул, тень мелькнула в свете вспыхнувших фар…* (С. Кинг. Стоянка)

*Правда, нашел **брелок автомобильной сигнализации** — без ключей, без обгорелостей, как если бы он вывалился из горящего вертолета* (В. Колычев. Волчьи законы тайги) .

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет примерно так: *пульт управления автомобильной сигнализацией, выполненный в форме брелока.* Сокращённо я бы назвал его просто **брелоком автомобильной сигнализации.**